# Hashmap Name at Runtime

Tags: java, hashmap

How we can name the HashMap at runtime:

for eg

```
String s="wow"
```

and i want to have a hashmap created at runtime as below

```
HashMap<String,String> wow=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

how we can acheive the same

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: This does not work in Java. What do you want to do?

Comment: for what you are saying, it seems that every time you create a string, you want to create a variable. Even if it was possible, I am wondering how useful it could be

Comment: @ Oliver @ sinclair  @ Macro............

I need to read a file and save the content of the file in some hashmap and with the condition that file name should me same as of hashMap name.......As i will be get the name of file at rumtime so will have to create the hashmap @ runtime too....